# Liferay: Inter-browser session

Tags: session, cross-browser, liferay, persist

The story is like this: using Liferay, if a user is logged-in on one browser and attempts to log-in on another browser (or another machine), then he should have the option of continuing that sesion (i.e. copy all the session attributes from that session and kill it from the first browser) or starting a new one (killing the session on the first machine).

I'd like to know if Liferay has support for something like this. I'm thinking that persisting the session attributes to the DB and getting them back in the second browser (e.g. using a PreLoginAction) might be a solution. I'm curious if there is a provided method of persisting the session and also a way to invalidate / kill the session on the first browser when the second one copies it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following properties in your portal-ext.properties and restart the server

```
#
    # Set the following to true if users are allowed to have simultaneous logins
    # from different sessions. This property is not used unless the property
    # "live.users.enabled" is set to true.
    #
    auth.simultaneous.logins=true

##
## Live Users
##

    #
    # Set this to true to enable tracking via Live Users.
    #
    live.users.enabled=true
```